# Can I insert more data in a MongoDB document without replacing the existing data? Update function replaces the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is the existing record

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5cbd9009740fb12e08b5592f"
    },
    "item": "ABC",
    "res_name": "XYZ",
    "price": "450",
    "category": "Main course"
}
```

I want this to happen but on using `update()` existing data is replaced

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5cbd9009740fb12e08b5592f"
    },
    "item": [
        "ABC"
         "DEF"
    ],
    "res_name": "XYZ"
    "price": [
        "150",
        "450"
    ],
    "category": [
        "Starters",
        "Main course"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your update code?

Comment: and please show the model scheme

Answer (score 0):

thats how update works, when you specify a field it replaces it.

now if you want to "append" values to an existing documents you have to 
do two things:

First: change your model schema, right now your schema's category is a string, it cannot hold more than 1 value.
your new schema should have the following properties:

```
  {
    _id: ObjectId,
    item: Array,
    res_nameL Array,
    price: Array,
    category: Array
    }
```

Second: it seems like you're updating a single document so i recommend using [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) instead of update. now your new query would look a little like this:

```
model.findOneAndUpdate(
      query,
      {
       $push: {
          category: 'new_category'
            ...
           price: 'new_price'
        }
      })
```

this should give you the desired result.